# Set the server time to the local time

Tags: java, sql

I am storing arrival time data on openshift server. There is 6 hours difference between the server time and my local time therefore I am trying to set the server time to my local time to get the right `arrivaltime` in the request. It works if I delete `preparedTime.setTime(2, time); preparedTime.setTime(3, time);` and set the outcommenting line in SQL.

I appreciate any help.

```
String day = "";
switch (WDay) {
case 7:
    day = "sat";
    break;
case 1:
    day = "sun";
    break;
default:
    day = "mon-fri";

}

String sql = "SELECT route FROM arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops"
        + " ON arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id"
        + " WHERE weekday = ?" 
        //+ "and arrivaltime BETWEEN curtime() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND curtime() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE"
        + "and arrivaltime BETWEEN ? - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND ? + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE"
        + " and name LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement preparedTime = con.prepareStatement(sql);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);

preparedTime.setString(1, day);

Time time = new Time(cal.getTime().getTime());
preparedTime.setTime(2, time);
preparedTime.setTime(3, time);
preparedTime.setString(4, stopName);

ResultSet rsArrivaletime = preparedTime.executeQuery();
```

arrival time table:

```
    stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(arrivaltimes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
            +  " weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
            + "route INT(11) NOT NULL, "
            + "arrivaltime time NOT NULL,"
            + " stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )" );
```

Comment: Personally, I'd still set the server time to UTC, even if you store local times (like as is probable given what appears to be a public transportation db).  What's the actual _problem_ you're getting?  An error?  Incorrect time?  What version of Java are you using?  Java 8 has a new, **really** nice date/time library.  Oh, and [don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (or anything, really - it's a representation problem).

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach would be to store everything in UTC, and convert those UTC timestamps to local time in your application only during user input-output.

Here is a tutorial for timezone usage in java: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: do you mean storing the data in the arrivaltimes table in UTC too?

Comment: Exactly, store times in UTC in the database and in-memory during processing, too. This makes everything much simpler, you must only convert at two points: during input and during output.

Comment: I would really like to know the reason of the downvote, please!

Comment: It was not me it was someone else.

Comment: @TheTime: I did not want to imply it was you, as I do not know who it was, and you also don't seem to have enough reputation to downvote. ;)

Comment: Looking at his table again, it's clear that the use is different than what I thought: local time is actually the better option, because he's not logging.  It appears he's actually doing something like setup for public transportation planning.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I still think UTC should be the way to go, as it would shift quite tricky timezone conversion code to java's internals. If you want to (re)implement that, you will have a lot of trouble.

Comment: The problem is that he's doing something with future planning times, which _aren't_ a log.  Stuff gets weird when you store UTC for dates/times like that.  Say you have a meeting for 4PM, and then DST changes (not that it occurs, that when it happens changes): the meeting may change its time!  If he was creating an 'individual trip' table, I'd probably say go for local date/time + timezone, not UTC, but he's actually only storing time (not something you could use with a multi-timezone transportation system, but fine for local buses or whatever).

Comment: It is true, that you could simply use local time everywhere in the application if there is guarantee that only local times are involved. However, it is simply better to be generic, IMHO. You cannot know in advance whether the user will cross timezones or not...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse if I store the data with the type of `date/time` does that mean I have to store the date too? I will use it if it is possible solution.

Comment: Yes, you should store the date, too. It is much clear-cut that way, need no heuristics for overflows.

Comment: @TheTime - That changes the purpose of the table.  Currently you have "Every week on the given day this route has a stop visited at this (local) time".  Changing it would make it "At this particular date/time, this route will stop at the given location".  You'd have to put in a row for _every_ date... and I'd probably still recommend having the current table for other reasons.  Given your current table, you can derive the date portion.  This will depend heavily on what your db is really going to be user for (separate question here/Programmers.SE for design questions).

Comment: @TheTime - ...for instance, a different way to store the information is only the departure from the first station, and the trip time to the next stop (with something else for waits at stops).